# Adding a String in an ArrayList everytime a button is clicked

Tags: java, string, swing, arraylist

I am new to java and I am trying to create a quiz app for my final project using java. I want to add the text inputted in the textField to my ArrayList everytime the button is clicked. I tried making it but the ArrayList only contains one element even after inputting a text many times. here is the code:

```
public class AddQuestions implements ActionListener {

    public ArrayList<String> questions;
    JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel();
    JTextField question = new JTextField();
    JButton addButton = new JButton();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == addButton){
            while(addButton == e.getSource()){
                String value = question.getText();
                questions = new ArrayList<>();
                questions.add(value);
                System.out.println(value);
                question.setText("");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(questions);
        System.out.println(questions.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: You are always creating a new ArrayList with `questions = new ArrayList<>();` in the actionPerformed method. You'll need to initialize the List once and only add to when the button is clicked, not always create a new list.

Comment: Not only that, I also don't see the `ActionListener` being added anywhere. You may want to take a look at [_How to Write an Action Listener_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `while` as it is unecessary, because when the button is clicked `actionPerformed()` will fire only once.

Also, `questions = new ArrayList<>()` inside `actionPerformed()` will always re-initialize the object `questions` to a new memory locations, hence the loss of the values you had added to it before.

```java
public class AddQuestions implements ActionListener {

  public ArrayList<String> questions=new ArrayList<>();
  JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel();
  JTextField question = new JTextField();
  JButton addButton = new JButton();
  
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == addButton){
      
      String value = question.getText();
      questions.add(value);
      System.out.println(value);
      question.setText("");
      
      
    }
    System.out.println(questions);
    System.out.println(questions.size());
    
  }
}
```

I suggest you read more about java by reading [*Java Programming* by Joyce Farrell](https://books.google.de/books/about/Java_Programming.html?id=-EWDtAEACAAJ), it is a great book for beginners. It has a ton of programming exercises for you to memorize java.

Comment: The while-loop makes the surrounding if-statement redundant. But even worse, in case its condition is fulfilled, it will loop indefinitely. I wouldn't say it is "unnecessary", but rather "unwanted" or an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when after clicking on the Button the new object is creating for ArrayList So you need to initialize the object of ArrayList before the event i.e. above the actionPerformed event method.